# How to customize the error handling when user choose not to purchase an item in iOS InApp Purchase?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

For example, when user asked to login during InApp purchase, they can click on the "Cancel" button, then the app will shoe

```
Can't connect to the iTunes Store
```

Is it possible to use our own callback instead of this standard message?

Answer (score 8):

I believe you don't get the alert with "Can't connect to the iTunes Store
" , I suspect you are showing alert view with the error in callback.

I have checked on the iOS 5 and 4.3. if you are NOT seeing this 4.3 and up I would not worry about that.

you can check if user cancelled the transaction with following code

Try following code inside  `restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError`

```
if (error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled || error.code == SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed){
    NSLog(@"User Cancelled");
}
```

I know it looks little confusing but works great, it works even user canceled on Restore or New Purchase.

Comment: Your if statement can be much more clearly expressed as: `if (error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled || error.code == SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed)`. This can be proved using truth tables.

Answer (score 1):

The system does not display any alert when a purchase is canceled, it's up to your application. See Step #10 in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html).

Basically, it goes like this :

The method `paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` of your `transactionObserver` is called whenever a transaction begins, succeeds, or fails. If it fails, the `-[SKPaymentTransaction error]` will contain a regular NSError. You can then check its code and act accordingly.

The known codes are : (from `<StoreKit/SKError.h>`)

```
// error codes for the SKErrorDomain
enum {
    SKErrorUnknown,
    SKErrorClientInvalid,       // client is not allowed to issue the request, etc.
    SKErrorPaymentCancelled,    // user cancelled the request, etc.
    SKErrorPaymentInvalid,      // purchase identifier was invalid, etc.
    SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed    // this device is not allowed to make the payment
};
```

You probably want to check at least for SKErrorPaymentCancelled and SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed.

Another interesting point is that the NSError contains a `localizedDescription` which you can display in an `UIAlertView`. That's where the "Can't connect to the iTunes Store" text probably comes.

(Also, possibly related : the Sandbox store used to test In-App purchase is flakey, which may explain the error.)

Answer (score 0):

While I was testing I would not get that message when canceling the login, but only messages generated by my code:

Are you sure you are not triggering the message within the `SKPaymentQueue Callback` method `paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` for transaction state `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`?

In case of canceled transaction, the `transaction.error.code` is set to `SKErrorPaymentCancelled`. In such cases one can omit any error pop ups or show their own.