# restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError: Error Code 0 (SKErrorUnknown) on Cancel

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

So basically, I want to display an alert when the restoring of completed transactions fails for some network/iTunes-specific reason, but **not** when the user taps 'Cancel' on the Apple ID/Password prompt.

In my implementation of:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
```

...I am testing `error.code` against `SKErrorPaymentCancelled` (perhaps I should also test against `SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed`, but that's not relevant now).

Still, the alert showed anyway when tapping 'cancel'. NS-Logging its value showed that `error.code == 0` (i.e., `SKErrorUnknown`).

This is happening on iOS 4.3.1, Xcode 4.2, build 4C199 (sandbox store, of course).

I have checked similar questions, but what is answered there is not what is happening in my case (that is, what I'm already doing should yield the correct behavior)... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check against these. Should be enough.

```
// error codes for the SKErrorDomain
enum {
    SKErrorUnknown,
    SKErrorClientInvalid,       // client is not allowed to issue the request, etc.
    SKErrorPaymentCancelled,    // user cancelled the request, etc.
    SKErrorPaymentInvalid,      // purchase identifier was invalid, etc.
    SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed    // this device is not allowed to make the payment
};
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/9017990/129202.

So what I do is I do a switch on the error.code, and only show an error when the code is not SKErrorPaymentCancelled. The user probably knows he/she pushed the cancel button (when entering user/pass).

So `SKErrorPaymentCancelled` should catch the cancel. If cancel button throws another error code, then there's a problem with that iOS version?

Answer (score 3):

I've found that on iOS Simulator, cancelling fails with error code 0 (`SKErrorUnknown`). But if you run it on the device, it correctly returns `SKErrorPaymentCancelled`. This seems to apply on iOS 9 as well.

Comment: The same goes for `SKErrorPaymentCancelled/SKErrorUnknown` when `transaction.transactionState` is `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`. Kind of annoying. I'm counting error code `0` as a `cancel` now too, for both these processes.